# Is this the correct procedure for parametric derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm practicing parametric and polar derivatives, in some of those i have trouble with the answers because they don't look "nice", i know there is no parameters of whats is supposed to be "nice" but in fact this kind of trouble commontly ends with a very small expression

in particular with this: $$x=e^{2t} \cos^{2}(t)$$  $$y=e^{2t} \sin^{2}(t)$$ find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for that i use  $\frac{y'}{x'}$
then $$x'=2e^{2t}( \sin^2(t) + \cos(2t))$$ and $$y'=2e^{2t}( \cos^2(t) - \sin(2t))$$
(aplying the product, power and chain rule, etc) after this doing $$\frac {x'=2e^{2t}( \sin^2(t) + \cos(2t))}{y'=2e^{2t}( \cos^2(t) - \sin(2t))}$$
$$\frac {x'=( \sin^2(t) + \cos(2t))}{y'=( \cos^2(t) - \sin(2t))}$$ and beyond this point i miss because in my answer page this must be
$$ \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {1+\tan(t)}{\cot(t)-1}$$

Comment: Hint: Double check $x'$ and $y'$.

Comment: Your $x'$ and $y'$ look a bit off to me. Example $x'=2e^{2t} \cdot \cos^2(t)+e^{2t}\cdot 2\cos(t)(-\sin(t))=2e^{2t}(\cos^2(t)-\cos(t)\sin(t))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

$$
\begin{align}
x'&=2e^{2t}\cos t\left(\cos t-\sin t\right)\\
y'&=2e^{2t}\sin t\left(\sin t+\cos t\right)\\
\end{align}$$
Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2e^{2t}\sin t\left(\sin t+\cos t\right)}{2e^{2t}\cos t\left(\cos t-\sin t\right)}
&=\frac{\sin t\left(\sin t+\cos t\right)}{\cos t\left(\cos t-\sin t\right)}\\
&=\frac{\cos^2 t}{\cos^2 t}\frac{\sin t\left(\sin t+\cos t\right)}{\cos t\left(\cos t-\sin t\right)}\\
&=\frac{\tan t\left(\tan t+1\right)}{1-\tan t}\\
&=\frac{\tan t+1}{\cot t-1}
\end{align}
$$